# Java using Eclipse ADT

Tags: java, eclipse, adt

I am using Eclipse ADT to learn Java.  I used ADT for an intro to Android course on the MOOC coursera platform. Going through that course, I see that learning Java is needed.

I am working through a java book: JAVA in easy steps by Mike Mcgrath

**This lesson is teaching: Passing an argument.  The code I have entered in ADT is:**

```
package com.javatutorial.hello;

public class Option {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {
        if ( args[0].equals( "-en"))
        {
            System.out.println( "English option");
        }
        else if ( args[0].equals( "-es"))
        {
            System.out.println( "Spanish option");
        }
        else System.out.println( "Unrecognized option");
    }
}
```

**When I run the program I get this exception error:**

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.javatutorial.hello.Option.main(Option.java:5)
```

So far I have figured out solutions to problems I have run into, but need help for this one.  Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably not passing any arguments to the function. In the `Run As` dialog, you need to set the arguments to the program. If this isn't set correctly, your index into the array is invalid.

Alternatively, you can check that `args` has been properly passed with options by checking

```
if(args.length >= 1) {
    // now try to index into args.
}
```

This correctly prevents the ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the case that the user isn't required to pass an option.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the application you need to define almost one input argument due you are using it (args[0])

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a control first, also you HAVE to [pass](http://theopentutorials.com/totwp331/wp-content/uploads/how-to-pass-command-line-arguments-in-eclipse-ide_680/cmdline-7.jpg?eb9eb8) it some argument.

```
package com.javatutorial.hello;


public class Option {
    public static void main ( String[] args ) {

      if(args.length!=0){
        if ( args[0].equals( "-en"))
        {
            System.out.println( "English option");
        }
        else if ( args[0].equals( "-es"))
        {
            System.out.println( "Spanish option");
        }
        else System.out.println( "Unrecognized option");
    }}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Run your application from cmd (Windows) or terminal (if you work on Linux):

```
javac Option.java
java Option -en
```

You should add at least one argument after java Option